# Diffeomorphism compact perturbation

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: X \rightarrow X$ be a Diffeomorphism and $X$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $g:X \rightarrow X$ be a $C^1_c$, i.e. g has compact support. 
I have to show now, that $\exists \varepsilon$ such that for all $|\lambda|<\varepsilon$ $f+\lambda g $ is Diffeomorphism.

Ideas: I want to use the implicit function theorem, but I don't know how to use it. 
Is it important, that $X$ is finite dimensional? If yes, should I use a basis?
Why $g$ has compact support? Do we need this assumption? 
 Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* On the compact support of $g$, the derivative of $f$ assumes its nonzero minimum and the derivative of $g$ its maximum